# Boto3 version mismatch inside the Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

Here (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html), AWS is saying that the `python3.11` should have the boto3 `1.28.72`. However, when I create a Lambda function from the console, the boto3 version is `1.27.1`.

I have created a new Lambda function (using AWS console) and then run the following snippet to check the boto3 version.

```py
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(f'Boto3 version: {boto3.__version__}')
    }
```

Region: `us-east-1`
Runtime: `Python 3.11 (x86_64)`

Response:

```json
Response
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "\"Boto3 version: 1.27.1\""
}
```

Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: Suspect a documentation bug, or someone hit 'publish changes' too early.

Comment: @jarmod Thanks for replying. Should I create a support ticket on their side? Actually, AWS released this update a while ago (about a month ago, I think). Then, I thought maybe I should wait, and it would be solved, but the issue still persists. TBH, I'm not sure what the action item here is and what I can do to notify them about this problem.

Comment: Options include raising a doc bug via the feedback mechanism at that page, raise a [support ticket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awssupport/latest/user/case-management.html), or roll your own [Python Lambda Layer](https://github.com/jeromevdl/boto3-lambda-layer) while you wait.

Comment: I submitted some feedback on the Documentation page.

Comment: @jarmod
@JohnRotenstein
They got back to me and mentioned that this is a document issue from their side. Also, told me that they already fixed it. But I think, by mistake, they changed the `py3.12` boto3 version instead of `py3.11`. So, still waiting for the issue to be fixed. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html

Comment: Second Update: Now, the link is showing the correct versions. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html